# can't get firebase_url in google-services.json

Tags: c#, firebase, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to save data to Firebase Firestore Database and I need firebase_url.

I download google-services.json, the url should be in "project_info" but it doesnt.

So where can I get this firebase_url?

Answer (score 1):

Normally, the firebase url could be found in google-services.json. If you do not find it, you could get the url from the Firebase Console.

**Firebase Console> Choose the specific project> Realtime Database in Build> Choose Data**

[image]

Comment: I am not using realtime database, I am using Firestore database. How can I find in Firestore?

Comment: For the Firebase Console, only Realtime Database could be found. Try the link from Realtime Database.

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing here.  We have some tooling that [automates the steps](https://developers.mattermost.com/contribute/mobile/unsigned/) to switch the underlying Android firebase properties.  These properties come via [Google Service Grade Plugin](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin) and a new `google-services.json` src file.

We used to get the property when downloading from Firebase console.